# Type decaying stl iterator

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have an interface that returns a range of values. The implementation of this interface may use different containers to provide those numbers.

```
class MyClassI
{
public:
  virtual std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator> Numbers() const = 0;
}

class MyClassC : public MyClassI
{
public:
  virtual std::pair<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator> Numbers() const 
     { return std::make_pair(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(); }
private:
   std::vector<int> numbers;
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to "decay" the container type away from the iterator.

```
class MyClassI
{
public:
  virtual std::pair<decayed_iterator<int>, decayed_iterator<int>> Numbers() const = 0;
}
```

I can of course put the original iterator on the heap and I can wrap that pointer with a template class to provide on the value type as an iterator.

I wonder if there is already something like that in boost or something off-the-self.

I can imagine something like the std/boost function, where the callable is decayed (if it is a function or a struct) and the "state" part is stored inside the object if it is small enough, to avoid heap allocation - if possible.

Comment: Do you mean a polymorphic iterator type? In other words an iterator baseclass (or baseclass template) and different derived iterators for various container types?

Comment: Yes. It would be something like IEnumerator<T> in C#, so it does not leak out more implementation detail (container type) than needed. I would need it so that I can use it as a method return value or take it as a method parameter. And preferably I do not want to make those methods template functions.

Comment: You can just create that! A base class, and derived class templates....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems boost has already the answer. The "Range" library provides a range adaptor(boost::adaptors::type_erased), which decays away the container or the other already applied adaptors. So we finally get a boost::any_range, which beside the iterated type has some other parameters, but not any more the container

[https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/type_erased.html](http://Boost%20example)